# Update table with row number

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

Evidently I did not ask my question properly the last time.

I need to update a table with a variable and data from another table.  At the same time, I would like to add an ascending row number.  Is this possible?

Here is the code that creates the table:

```
    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[SC_Data](
[Rownumber]int IDENTITY(1,1)NOT FOR REPLICATION NOT NULL,
[Division]varchar(50)null,
[Vendor]varchar(50)null,
[ID]varchar(50)null,
[ItemNumber]varchar(50)null,
[ProductName]varchar(50)null,
[BrandClass]varchar(50)null,
[WebID]varchar(50)null,
[Brand]varchar(50)null,
[MktDescription]varchar(500)null,
[MktCopy]varchar(500)null,
[B1]varchar(50)null,
[B2]varchar(50)null,
[B3]varchar(50)null,
[B4]varchar(50)null,
[B5]varchar(50)null,
[B6]varchar(50)null,
[B7]varchar(50)null,
[B8]varchar(50)null,
[B9]varchar(50)null,
[B10]varchar(50)null,
[Notes]varchar(255)null,
[PrimaryFileName]varchar(100)null,
[Color]varchar(40)null,
[LiveDate]date null,
[SampleType]varchar(50)null,
[User]varchar(100)null,
[FileName]text null
Constraint[PK_SC_Data]primary key clustered
(
        [Rownumber]ASC
)with(pad_index=off,statistics_norecompute=off,ignore_dup_key=off,
allow_row_locks=on,allow_page_locks=on)
)on[Primary]
```

I have a similar table created from an import that does not have the fields [FileName] and [Rownumber].  I would like to copy all of the other data into this table from that table and update the [FileName] with a variable @FileName

Comment: Are you saying that after you insert a row into this table you want to get the `RowNumber` out for the record you just inserted?  The table alone isn't enough.  What have you tried?  can you sqlfiddle it?

Answer (score 0):

Just select from the other table into this table, excluding the "Rownumber" field, and using @FileName as the source for your "FileName" column:

```
INSERT [dbo].[SC_Data](
    [Division],[Vendor],[ID],[ItemNumber],[ProductName],[BrandClass],[WebID]
    ,[Brand],[MktDescription],[MktCopy],[B1],[B2],[B3],[B4],[B5],[B6],[B7]
    ,[B8],[B9],[B10],[Notes],[PrimaryFileName,[Color],[LiveDate],[SampleType]
    ,[USER],[FileName]
)
SELECT   [Division],[Vendor],[ID],[ItemNumber],[ProductName],[BrandClass],[WebID]
    ,[Brand],[MktDescription],[MktCopy],[B1],[B2],[B3],[B4],[B5],[B6],[B7]
    ,[B8],[B9],[B10],[Notes],[PrimaryFileName,[Color],[LiveDate],[SampleType]
    ,[USER],@FileName
FROM dbo.OtherTable;
```